# Replacing values in data frame column using another data frame

Tags: r

I have a table of pending bills in the Scottish Parliament. One of the columns (BillTypeID) is populated with numbers that indicate what type of bill each one is (there are seven different types of bills).

I have another table that describes which number corresponds to which bill types ( 1 = "Executive", 2 = "Member's", etc.)

I want to replace the number in my main table with the corresponding string that describes the type for each bill.

Data:

```
bills <- jsonlite::fromJSON(url("https://data.parliament.scot/api/bills"))
bill_stages <- jsonlite::fromJSON(url("https://data.parliament.scot/api/billstages"))
```

Comment: You will probably want to `merge()` the two data sets. See `?merge`

Comment: Thanks! Merging didn't seem to work as the two tables are not the same length.

Comment: they don't have to be the same length.  See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably a duplicate but I can't find the corresponding answer ...

The easiest way to do this is with `merge()`.

```
d1 <- data.frame(billtype=c(1,1,3,3),
          bill=c("first","second","third","fourth"))
d2 <- data.frame(billtype=c(1,2,3),
                 billtypename=c("foo","bar","bletch"))
d3 <- merge(d1,d2)
## 
##   billtype   bill billtypename
## 1        1  first          foo
## 2        1 second          foo
## 3        3  third       bletch
## 4        3 fourth       bletch
```

... then drop the `billtype` column if you don't want it any more. You can probably do it slightly more efficiently with `match()` (see my answer to the linked question).